# Coordinating colour and shape in legend and plot consistently using geom point and line

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom, geom-point

Trying to create graphs using ggplot2, and I am coming with a strange peoblem I can't seem to solve. I've looked at other answers on stack overflow but they don't seem to fix the problem. Between different samples, the colours and shapes used in the legend/plot change between each plot.

Using the below code I get the proper graphs and everything matches

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(formattable)
library(cowplot)
yield <- read.csv("yield79.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
npq <- read.csv("npq79.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
yno <- read.csv("yno79.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
ql <- read.csv("ql79.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

plotData <- function(inputData, mutant, labelY, mult=0) {
  my_colours <- c("#F8766D", "#00B0F6", "#00BF7D", "#A3A500", "#E76BF3")
  print(paste("working on ", labelY))
  return (ggplot(inputData) + 
    
    geom_point( aes(x = sec, y = mult + (-1)^mult*col.0, colour = "col-0"), shape = "square", size = 2) +
    geom_line(  aes(x = sec, y = mult + (-1)^mult*col.0, colour = "col-0"), size = 0.7) + 
    
    geom_point( aes(x = sec, y = mult + (-1)^mult*pgr5.1, colour = "pgr5-1"),  shape = "circle", size = 2) +
    geom_line(  aes(x = sec, y = mult + (-1)^mult*pgr5.1, colour = "pgr5-1"), size = 0.7) + 
    
    geom_point( aes(x = sec, y = mult + (-1)^mult*pgr5.cas, colour = "pgr5-cas"), shape = "diamond", size = 2) +
    geom_line(  aes(x = sec, y = mult + (-1)^mult*pgr5.cas, colour = "pgr5-cas"), size = 0.7) + 
    
    geom_point( aes(x = sec, y = mult + (-1)^mult*npq4.1, colour = "npq4-1"), shape = "triangle", size = 2) +
    geom_line(  aes(x = sec, y = mult + (-1)^mult*npq4.1, colour = "npq4-1"), size = 0.7) + 
    
    geom_point( aes(x = sec, y = mult + (-1)^mult*mutant, colour = "t79"), shape = "asterisk", size = 2) +
    geom_line(  aes(x = sec, y = mult + (-1)^mult*mutant, colour = "t79"), size = 0.7) +
    
    theme_classic() + 
    scale_colour_discrete(
        name = "",
        labels = c(
                   "Col-0",
                   expression(italic("pgr5-1")),
                   expression(italic("pgr5-cas")),
                   expression(italic("npq4-1")),
                   expression(italic("t79"))
                 )
    ) +
    guides(
      colour = guide_legend(override.aes = 
        list(
          shape = c("square", "circle", "diamond", "triangle", "asterisk"),
          colour = my_colours
        )
      )
    ) +
    theme(legend.text.align = 0) +
    xlab("Time (s)") + ylab(labelY)
  )
  }

testMutant <- function(mutant) {
  yii <- plotData(yield, yield[[mutant]], "Y(II)")
  print("yii worked")
  npq4 <- plotData(npq, npq[[mutant]], "NPQ")
  print("npq4 worked")
  no <- plotData(yno, yno[[mutant]], "Y(NO)")
  print("no worked")
  ql2 <- plotData(ql, ql[[mutant]], "1-qL", 1)
  print("ql2 worked")
  
  return (plot_grid(yii, npq4, ql2, no, labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), label_size = 10))

}

output <- testMutant("t79")
output
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MToU1.png)
But if I change the data to be from pale, the following occurs and legend colour is not the same as the plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(formattable)
library(cowplot)
yield <- read.csv("yieldpale.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
npq <- read.csv("npqpale.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
yno <- read.csv("ynopale.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
ql <- read.csv("qlpale.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

plotData <- function(inputData, mutant, labelY, mult=0) {
  my_colours <- c("#F8766D", "#00B0F6", "#00BF7D", "#A3A500", "#E76BF3")
  print(paste("working on ", labelY))
  return (ggplot(inputData) + 
    
    geom_point( aes(x = sec, y = mult + (-1)^mult*col.0, colour = "col-0"), shape = "square", size = 2) +
    geom_line(  aes(x = sec, y = mult + (-1)^mult*col.0, colour = "col-0"), size = 0.7) + 
    
    geom_point( aes(x = sec, y = mult + (-1)^mult*pgr5.1, colour = "pgr5-1"),  shape = "circle", size = 2) +
    geom_line(  aes(x = sec, y = mult + (-1)^mult*pgr5.1, colour = "pgr5-1"), size = 0.7) + 
    
    geom_point( aes(x = sec, y = mult + (-1)^mult*pgr5.cas, colour = "pgr5-cas"), shape = "diamond", size = 2) +
    geom_line(  aes(x = sec, y = mult + (-1)^mult*pgr5.cas, colour = "pgr5-cas"), size = 0.7) + 
    
    geom_point( aes(x = sec, y = mult + (-1)^mult*npq4.1, colour = "npq4-1"), shape = "triangle", size = 2) +
    geom_line(  aes(x = sec, y = mult + (-1)^mult*npq4.1, colour = "npq4-1"), size = 0.7) + 
    
    geom_point( aes(x = sec, y = mult + (-1)^mult*mutant, colour = "p2.8.pale1.1"), shape = "asterisk", size = 2) +
    geom_line(  aes(x = sec, y = mult + (-1)^mult*mutant, colour = "p2.8.pale1.1"), size = 0.7) +
    
    theme_classic() + 
    scale_colour_discrete(
        name = "",
        labels = c(
                   "Col-0",
                   expression(italic("pgr5-1")),
                   expression(italic("pgr5-cas")),
                   expression(italic("npq4-1")),
                   expression(italic("pale"))
                 )
    ) +
    guides(
      colour = guide_legend(override.aes = 
        list(
          shape = c("square", "circle", "diamond", "triangle", "asterisk"),
          colour = my_colours
        )
      )
    ) +
    theme(legend.text.align = 0) +
    xlab("Time (s)") + ylab(labelY)
  )
  }

testMutant <- function(mutant) {
  yii <- plotData(yield, yield[[mutant]], "Y(II)")
  print("yii worked")
  npq4 <- plotData(npq, npq[[mutant]], "NPQ")
  print("npq4 worked")
  no <- plotData(yno, yno[[mutant]], "Y(NO)")
  print("no worked")
  ql2 <- plotData(ql, ql[[mutant]], "1-qL", 1)
  print("ql2 worked")
  
  return (plot_grid(yii, npq4, ql2, no, labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), label_size = 10))

}

output <- testMutant("p2.8.pale1.1")
output
(ggsave("pale.png", width = 9.15, height = 5.5) )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6ZVZ.png)

Any ideas? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could do much easier by reshaping your data to "long" format and using `ggplot`s `facet`ting functionality:

once you've arrived at your data in "wide" format ...

```
## generate data:
d <- data.frame(parameter = gl(2, 10, labels = c('Y(II)', 'NPG')),
                `Col-0` = rnorm(20),
                `pgr5-1` = rnorm(20),
                Time = rep(1:10 * 60),
                check.names = FALSE
                )
```

```
> d |> head()
  parameter       Col-0      pgr5-1 Time
1     Y(II)  1.11822031  0.92483127   60
2     Y(II) -0.03029035  0.91094580  120
3     Y(II) -0.19066448 -0.89062498  180
4     Y(II) -0.41270402 -0.05741260  240
5     Y(II) -0.14732161  0.67413480  300
6     Y(II)  0.57088741 -0.04764788  360
```

... reshape them:

```
library(tidyr)

d <- d |>
  pivot_longer(c('Col-0', 'pgr5-1'),
               names_to = 'Mutant',
               values_to = 'Value'
               )
```

```
> d |> sample_n(6)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  parameter  Time Mutant   Value
  <fct>     <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
1 NPG         120 pgr5-1  0.631 
2 Y(II)       120 Col-0  -0.0303
3 NPG         540 pgr5-1  0.473 
4 Y(II)       600 Col-0  -0.260 
5 Y(II)       180 pgr5-1 -0.891 
6 Y(II)       480 pgr5-1 -0.708
```

now you can plot per parameter (in your case A-D) without the hazzle of creating and arranging separate plot objects like so:

```
library(ggplot2)

d |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = Value, color = Mutant)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = Mutant)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ parameter)
```

[image: facet a plot]